# What is the proper way to merge things into the production/release branch?

Tags: git

My team and I are currently working on a small project.

In order to do things properly, we are trying to follow a git branching model similar to what's described in https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/:

[image: git branching model]

One key difference with what's shown on the picture, though, regards the `hotfixes` branch:

- When a bug shows up in production, we have to fix the behaviour as fast as possible, and we often have to do that through a temporary solution (hardcoding stuff that shouldn't stay hardcoded, etc). This solution is developped on `hotfixes` then merged into `master` (which is the production branch)
- Once things have calmed down in production, we look into things more deeply and fix the issue properly on `develop`. In some cases, the issue may also be fixed on `develop` as a side-effect of other changes, e.g. by merging a feature branch that removes the faulty code entirely. Either way, the point is that the temporary hack that was deployed in production never makes it to `develop`

This may seem like a small difference, but it changes things down the line:

- At some point, what's on `develop` is put on a release branch (let's call it `pre-release`)
- After some testing and fixes, the release candidate is ready to go on the production branch, so we need to merge `pre-release` into `master`. We call `git checkout master; git merge --no-ff pre-release` and we're done... except we're not

**Let's get to the point:**

Something is very wrong with what I've just described. After we're done, what we have on `master` isn't simply the release candidate. It's the release candidate *plus* the hotfix commit from before. Since the changes in that commit must not be kept in production, this is a problem.

So here's the question: if `git checkout master; git merge --no-ff pre-release` is wrong here, what's the proper way to merge `pre-release` into `master`?

I mean, I could merge `hotfixes` into `develop` even though we don't need the commit, using `git checkout develop; git merge -s ours hotfixes` to ignore what's in it, but that doesn't quite feel like the proper way to solve this issue

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to merge `hotfix` into `develop` and then resolve changes normally? The branching model has that for a reason, and it would solve your problem.
The branching model does this (IMO) because not all hotfixes are "temporary solutions". Sometimes a hotfix will be the permanent solution - a trivial example is a "business critical typo in a user-facing message" - fixed in about 10 seconds, and it's going to stay.

Comment: The diagram preserves an important property: the head of develop is *always* the current production version plus some stuff. By transitivity, then, a release candidate is *also* the current production version plus some stuff. It's OK if part of "some stuff" in each case *reverts* the hot fix.

Comment: @Vlad274 It's not that no hotfix will ever make it to `develop`, but that some won't (because they're temporary, because they're made obsolete by other changes on `develop`, etc). The question is about what to do in those cases

Comment: @chepner what you say about preserving a property sounds good in theory, but 1) having to merge the hotfix into `develop` then instantly revert it feels wrong to me, 2) making my coworkers do it every time even though there is no effect on `develop` seems hard, 3) what if the file or function modified by the hotfix doesn't even exist anymore on `develop`? there isn't even a proper way to bring the hotfix commit to that branch...

Comment: "instantly revert it", this sounds to me like you still want to keep the bug on develop until it is properly fixed. Even though the fix is temporary, might even be considered a hack, it was implemented good enough to warrant being put into production (wasn't it?), so it should be good enough for development as well, even though immediately work on a fix that might end up obsoleting/reverting/removing all of that. Could you explain the reasoning behind **not** merging into development? Why do you not want the fix there as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow sounds reasonable in the great picture.

One thing you have to change with regards to hotfixes is that you must introduce a commit that reverses the unwanted hotfix solution.

There are two situations:

### The simple case

Branch `develop` does not make the hotfix unnecessary. At best, you just branch off of the hotfix and commit `git revert HEAD^` on top of it, then merge this commit into `develop`. Now you proceed as usual with the thorough fix of the problem, either on `develop` or on top of the reverted hotfix.

### The complicated case

Branch `develop` makes the hotfix obsolete. To override the changes of the hotfix, you first merge the parent of the hotfix to `develop`, then use `git merge -S ours` to ignore the hotfix changes.

Consider the following branching history. Regard each node name `ABC` as the contents of a file.

```
       ABC
      /   \
     |  / ABCx    <- hotfix (on master)
   ABDC | /|      <- change on develop makes hotfix obsolete
     | / / |
     v  /  |      <- git merge hotfix^ into develop
    ABDC   |      <- git merge -S ours hotfix into develop
      \   /
      ABDC        <- git merge develop into master
```

[Edit: *this is wrong:* As you can see, the last `git merge` sees "`D` was added on `develop`" and "`x` was added on `master`", therefore, the addition of both is the result of the merge.]

It is important to merge the commit before the hotfix in a regular manner, otherwise `git merge -s ours` would ignore all unmerged changes before the hotfix as well.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, in case 1. you're saying I could revert the temporary changes directly on `hotfix`, develop the proper fix there, then merge it into `develop`. That seems reasonable.

Comment: Can you give more explanations about case 2.? Why can't `git merge -S ours` be used on `develop` to have the hotfix commit as an ancestor without having the changes? What would happen to `master` if we were to merge `develop` into it after that?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show more details in the complicated case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but are you sure about what you're saying? I created a tiny repo on my computer to test it, and I end up with ABCD on master, not ABCDx

Comment: Now, this is embarassing. Thanks for beating me with the cluestick. `ABDC` is the correct outcome of the last merge. That means that `git merge -s ours` is a solution. There is a caveat, though. I'll update my answer.